# Export form data to excel is always giving empty file

Tags: wffm

I am trying to download WFFM data in excel file by Export to Excel button in Sitecore. I can see the data into dashboard but when I am going to download it is always downloading empty file.

Does anyone came across with same issue?

Sitecore version is 8.1

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have anything in log files related to this issue?

Comment: Sorry @TamásTárnok I didn't mention in question but I don't have any error in log files

Comment: Is it not working after the an upgrade or on a clean install?

Comment: @TamásTárnok not working after clean installation

Answer (score 0):

Processor request is not calling for export to excel button.Please go to path "/sitecore/client/Applications/WFFM/Resources/Parameters/ActionControl Parameters/ActionColumn/ActionGroup/ExportToExcel" in core database.Give the pipeline request name in click field(javascript:app.exportToExcel()).

Pipeline request will be in Sitecore.Wffm.services.config which is located in Appconfig/include/

```
<exportToExcel>
<processor type="Sitecore.WFFM.Services.Pipelines.ExportToExcel.ExportFormDataToExcel, Sitecore.WFFM.Services" />
</exportToexcel>
```